# How does useEffect react with a value that is initially undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect

If we have a variable in redux like
`const data = {};`

which after some API calls becomes `data = { task : "Some thing here"}`

How should the useEffect react? In my case it rendered more than 5k+ times.

Assume API call does take a noticable fraction of time

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(data.task){
    console.log('hy', someDeps);
  }
}[someDeps])
```

Comment: Is the value actually `undefined`, or is it an empty object? Effectively an effect runs whenever a dependency is not === the previous value (Meaning two different objects with identical content will still trigger the effect, which often trips people up)

Comment: If the dependency `=== undefined`, `useEffect` behaves as if there were no dependencies at all (different than with an empty dependency array) - which means it will run each time the component rerenders/updates.

Comment: @DBS the value gets changed with Redux, so according to me the initial data is an empty object but when it changes, it has a property action. The doubt I have is, the time when the value remains unknown, would it keep updating or what?

Comment: Basically, the effect will run if `oldDependencyValue !== newDependencyValue`. So whether the effect will run depends on whether the same empty object is passed in or a different empty object (Since objects are compared by reference). An easy way to get around that is to depend on a string value inside the object e.g. `[someDeps?.id]`

Comment: @Khalt - that's only if the dependency array is undefined. If the dependency array contains a value that is `undefined`, then that's completely fine. It sounds to me like the dependency in this effect is actually `[data.task]`

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `undefined` as the value of the array, it's the same as passing no value at all, i.e. the code will run on **every** render.

If, OTOH you pass `[undefined]` as the value of the array, it's the same as passing an empty array (`[]`) or an array of values that never change. I.e. the code will run only on the **initial** render.